# Add loader-div to any element on page while blurring the content below

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build an overlay which can be added to any element on the website which also blurries out the underlying content.
These are the css-classes I currently use:

```
.load-overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.1;
    opacity: 0.1;*/
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    min-height: 180px;
}

.load-spinner {
    border: 16px solid lightgrey;
    border-top: 16px solid #ff7d00;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -40px;
    margin-top: -40px;
}

.load-text {
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ff7d00;
    color: #999;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-style: italic;
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

To achieve what I want I extendend jQuery like this (using TypeScript):

```
$.fn.addLoader = function (loadText: string): JQuery {
    const overlayDiv = $("<div class=\"load-overlay\"></div>");
    const spinnerDiv = $("<div class=\"load-spinner\"></div>");
    overlayDiv.append(spinnerDiv);

    if (loadText) {
        const textDiv = $("<div class=\"load-text\">" + loadText + "</div>");
        overlayDiv.append(textDiv);
    }

    overlayDiv.appendTo(this.css("position", "relative"));

    return this;
}
```

What I now wanted to do is, make the content under the loader look blurry. To achieve this, I've added `this.css("filter", "blur(5px));` to the `addLoader` function.
However, now the loader itself is also blurry but this one should be clear and readable.

I guess it's somehow related to the positioning (absolute/relative) but I don't see it.

Comment: you should separate overlay and overlay content. overlay content should have higher z-index and everything non-blured should be appended to overlay content div. because it will blur everything contained in overlay div

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you're using the `.append()` method on the `.load-spinner` element, which makes the spinner the ***child*** of the `.load-overlay`.

Instead, you need to append the load spinner to the `<body>` element *after* you've appended the filter overlay.

Therefore:

```
$.fn.addLoader = function (loadText: string): JQuery {
// prepare divs as constants
const overlayDiv = $("<div class=\"load-overlay\" />");
const spinnerDiv = $("<div class=\"load-spinner\" />"); // Note here, you can self-close elements created by JQuery if they're empty.

//overlayDiv.append(spinnerDiv); // I've removed this from here as you don't need to append the spinner to the overlay.

if (loadText) {
    const textDiv = $("<div class=\"load-text\">" + loadText + "</div>");
    overlayDiv.append(textDiv);
}

// once this is all done, you then append the spinner to the body (or the parent container, whichever is preferable)
$('body').append(spinnerDiv);

overlayDiv.appendTo(this.css("position", "relative"));

return this;
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately it is not working. Also I need to mention that I'm not good in css & styling at all ;)

Comment: I've created a fiddle [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ecLLyrm9/).
As you can see, as long as the spinner isn't a child of the div with a filter, it won't have the effect applied to it.